# Hibernate 6 uses wrong JdbcType for custom user type

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a project that uses Quarkus 3.1.2.Final which uses `hibernate-core` in version 6.2.4.Final.

Here I have a custom user type for my custom class, which is used in an entity.

```
@Type(MyStringUserType.class)
public MyStringWrapper field;
```

When I execute a query with a condition that uses a function like `upper`, `substring`, etc. I get an exception.

Example

```
@Transactional
List<MyEntity> getByQuery() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
    Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);

    query.where(
            cb.equal(cb.upper(root.get("field")), new MyStringWrapper("SOME VALUE"))
    );
    TypedQuery<MyEntity> result = em.createQuery(query);
    return result.getResultList();
}
```

The exception:

> [ERROR] org.acme.UserTypeTest.testQuery  Time elapsed: 0.129 s  <<< ERROR!
>
> org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 1 of function upper() has type
> STRING, but argument is of type org.acme.MyStringWrapper
>
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.ArgumentTypesValidator.throwError(ArgumentTypesValidator.java:253)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.ArgumentTypesValidator.checkType(ArgumentTypesValidator.java:204)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.ArgumentTypesValidator.validate(ArgumentTypesValidator.java:98)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.AbstractSqmFunctionDescriptor.generateSqmExpression(AbstractSqmFunctionDescriptor.java:104)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.SqmFunctionDescriptor.generateSqmExpression(SqmFunctionDescriptor.java:117)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.upper(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:1541)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.upper(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:182)
> at org.acme.UserTypeTestBean.getByQuery(UserTypeTestBean.java:34)   at
> org.acme.UserTypeTestBean_Subclass.getByQuery$$superforward(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.acme.UserTypeTestBean_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
> [...]

When I do the same in Hibernate 5 it works fine.

I have two reproducers for this:

- https://github.com/timonzi/hibernate-user-type-query-reproducer
- https://github.com/timonzi/hibernate-user-type-query-reproducer-hibernate-5

Is there any chance to get such a constellation running with Hibernate 6?

What I found so far by debugging

The called method `org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.ArgumentTypesValidator#getJdbcType` returns a `VarbinaryJdbcType`, which then leads to (the throw of) an error in `org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.ArgumentTypesValidator#checkType` as Varbinary is no character type.

Here I would expect, that a `VarcharJdbcType` is used, as in my custom user type the `getSqlType` returns `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR`.

I also tried to define the type using `@JdbcType(VarcharJdbcType.class)` and `@JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR)` but nothing changed.

Comment: In the meantime, I have found a Hibernate issue that describes a similar problem: [HHH-16751](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16751)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [HHH-16751](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16751), the problem should be fixed in version 6.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found a **hacky workaround** in the meantime, but currently I don't know the consequences - but at least my example works with this.

If an attribute converter is added to the property in the entity - or defined globally like in the following example - the user type is still used and the attribute converter methods are not called (!). BUT it now uses a `VarcharJdbcType` instead of the `VarbinaryJdbcType` like mentioned in my description.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DummyConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyStringWrapper, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final MyStringWrapper o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("dummy converter should not be called");
    }

    @Override
    public MyStringWrapper convertToEntityAttribute(final String o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("dummy converter should not be called");
    }
}
```

I have to investigate possible side effects, but at least my query works with this. Maybe this information helps someone - also possible the Hibernate developers.

But at the end of course Hibernate should fix this problem ([HHH-16751](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16751)).